# Exporting org-mode to HTML: Include custom sitemap above the title

Tags: org-mode

I would like to include a short sitemap like

```
[[./page1.org]] [[./page2.org]] [[./page3.org]]
```

which I have contained in a file called `sitemap-banner.org`, but I would like for this to appear at the top of the page, above the title. When I start an `org-mode` document with

```
#+INCLUDE: sitemap-banner.org
#+TITLE: pagetitle
```

and export as HTML, the title still appears above this banner. Is there a way to change this behavior, or are there any other suggestions for including such a sitemap?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this must be solved through CSS placement rules.